# How to implement switch accounts option in Django

Tags: django, authentication, multiple-login

Consider an application where there is a company account and employee account. I want to add employees as admin of the company. Then the admin should be able to switch account with the company. Is it possible to do the switch account option?
I am a beginner in Django. Can anyone help me with this problem?

I am adding my user model here:

```py
# Custom user
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    """ Custom user model"""
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, validators=[EmailValidator])
    is_company = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_employee = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='username')

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.username}"

# Company user
class CompanyAccount(TimeStampedModel):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='company')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)
    website_url = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    industry = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    founded_year = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    headquarters = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"

# Employee user
class Employee(TimeStampedModel):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="profile")
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    job_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

    company = models.ForeignKey(CompanyAccount, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="employee")


    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user.username}"
```

Comment: Please add your code otherwise we'd have to write a full user model for you, it is possible though and easily achievable.

Comment: Please provide sample code